# android adb insert contacts and need to hit "done" to complete

Tags: android, android-activity, adb

I am using emulator (android 2.3.3)

```
adb shell "am start -a android.intent.action.INSERT -t vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact -e name 'Android Auto' -e phone 51115111"
```

this command just help me launch "new contact" and fill in name and telephone. I need to hit done on the screen to complete the insertion.

Is there a way to finish the procedure without manual intervention?

Answer (score 8):

@Shimon Elbaz is right.

'Back key' helps to save changes.
For me (on Android 4.4.2) next script works:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.INSERT -t vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact -e name 'Android Auto22232342' -e phone 51115111
adb shell input keyevent 4
adb shell input keyevent 4
adb shell input keyevent 4
```

We need to press HW Back button 3 times:
- 1st hides the keypad
- 2nd closes ContactEditorActivity (saves the contact)
- 3rd closes contact info activity

My task was to add 50 contacts onto device, for that I've wrote a simply bash script:

```
contactCount=50
if (( $# != 0 ))
    then
        let contactCount=$1
fi
for (( c=0; c<contactCount; c++))
do
    adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.INSERT -t vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact -e name 'Test'$c -e phone 511151$c
    adb shell input keyevent 4
    adb shell input keyevent 4
    adb shell input keyevent 4
    wait $pid
done
adb shell input keyevent 4
```

1. To add 50 contacts run script without parameters:

   ./script.sh
2. To add other count of contacts add a parameter:

   ./script.sh

   Ex. to add 3 contacts:

   ./script.sh 3

Also, I think there is some easier way to do this actions, I'll be happy to see it =)

Thanks for attention.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with keyevent, but `input tap 1045 100` simulates tapping the screen. The x, y coordinates needed a lot of trial and error to find, since 'visualize taps' in developer options does not seem to work for this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a key event. 
basically keyevents can be sent via adb shell as well using - 
adb.exe shell input keyevent #

the key event are mostly similar between vendors and you can use [this chart](http://thecodeartist.blogspot.co.il/2011/03/simulating-keyevents-on-android-device.html) to find the right one:

if it does not match the list - try playing with it a bit.

also notice, that in many devices, once you open the intent with the information, pressing the "Home" or "Return" keys will automatically save the changes.

Comment: Did someone find the actual save key as key event?
Or is there an option which I can pass via the ADB?